# Extract the specific data from the file

Tags: c++, parsing, include, getline

I have a file(as  text) from which I should extract all included files names.
The implementation should be in `C++`
What I thought to do is to read a file line after line (`getline`)
check if line starts from `#include` - how do I do that?(there could be leading spaces)
and after that extract the file name - the string which is between " " - how do I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Show us what did you try (code) and at which point you're having problems.

Comment: Why don't you get the string and check it char-by-char or use `regex`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all an include may be placed either between `<>` or between `""` so you have to check for both.

Next - best way to do what you try is using regular expressions. If you are using `c++11` they will be part of the standard and you should be good to go. If that is not the case maybe try [boost::regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) for instance.

If using regular expressions is not an option you will have to implement your own parsing but this will be error-prone and most probably you will miss some freaky edge-case. If I have to I would implement such parsing by going over the file line by line. Than I would check if the line contains `#include` as substring and verify there are only whitespaces before it. If the line **does** have the mentioned substring I would than iterate over the remaining part of the line to parse the part between `<>` or `""`.